# Can I connect to my app that I've deployed on Meteor and run a method manually?

Tags: meteor

So I've deployed my app to e.g. `myapp.meteor.com`. I want to run a Meteor  Method to clean up my database, but I don't really want to make a new button just to run this method. Is there anyway I can connect to the remote server through my terminal and run the method through there?

Also, I'm not referring to connecting to the remote mongo db.

Comment: Sure post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just do so from your browser's console (F12 to open generally):

```
Meteor.call('cleanDB');
```

Note that for such a method you might want to [add some validations server-side](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_userId).

Comment: LOL thanks! Don't know why that didn't occur to me at all.

Comment: @ABC Haha, it happens I suppose. Many bugs happen during the night!